# Customers did not transfer during migration. How best to proceed?

Tags: customer, migrate

```
Migration from Magento 1.9.4 --> Magento 2.4.2-p1
```

As far as I can tell my running of the Magento Migration tool transferred everything except the orders which we didn't want but I just noticed we are missing Customers also. *What would be the best way to proceed?* Shall I re-run the Magento Migration Tool or use the

```
System --> Import/Export --> Export/Dataflow - Profiles
```

option? **If Import/Export - would it be better to use the 'Export' option or 'Dataflow - Profiles'?**

---

**RESOLVED**: I ran the **reindex via SSH** as suggested by Pawan and it worked!

Comment: with Migration tool customer should migrate. did you checked record in database ? have you run indexing ?

Comment: @Pawan Re-indexing actually worked! Thank you.

Comment: Glad to know :) can i put my comment as an answer so you can accept ?

Comment: @Pawan sure - go ahead! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am putting my comment as an answer here:

As you are using default migration tool, it should migrate all customer by default.

You can first check database of Magento 2 for customer record and If you found record, You just need to run `re-indexing`.